# Separating into html page, javascript page, and css page

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I'm writing a code to toggle words on a page to show and hide the word's meaning. When the HTML and JavaScript are in one file it works fine but when I try to put them into different files the code does not work. how would I go about fixing this? i have check the console and no errors have popped up.

JS:

```
document.getElementById("stream").addEventListener("click", function(){
        var element = document.getElementById("stream_meaning");
        element.classList.toggle("mystyle");
});

document.getElementById("taxi").addEventListener("click", function(){
        var element = document.getElementById("taxi_meaning");
        element.classList.toggle("mystyle");
});

document.getElementById("spend").addEventListener("click", function(){
        var element = document.getElementById("spend_meaning");
        element.classList.toggle("mystyle");
});

document.getElementById("refer").addEventListener("click", function(){
        var element = document.getElementById("refer_meaning");
        element.classList.toggle("mystyle");
});

document.getElementById("offspring").addEventListener("click", function(){
        var element = document.getElementById("offspring_meaning");
        element.classList.toggle("mystyle");
    });
```

FULL HTML (with script linked):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>dictionary</title>
    <link href="styles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <title>Dictionary</title>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
    <li id="taxi">
        taxi
        <span id="taxi_meaning" class="meaning">
            a car with a driver who you pay to take you somewhere.
        </span>
    </li>
    <li id="stream">
        stream
        <span id="stream_meaning" class="meaning">
            water that flows naturally along a fixed route formed by a channel cut into rock or ground, usually at ground level.
        </span>
    </li>
    <li id="offspring">
        offspring

        <span id="offspring_meaning" class="meaning">
            In the case of the guinea pig, the number of offspring varies between two and five.
        </span>
    </li>
    <li id="spend">
        spend

        <span id="spend_meaning" class="meaning">
            to give money as a payment for something.
        </span>
    </li>
    <li id="refer">
        refer

        <span id="refer_meaning" class="meaning">
            to tell a reader to look somewhere else in a book for more information about something.
        </span>
    </li>
</ul>
<script type="text/javascript" src="book.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
li {
            font-weight: bold;
            font-size: 40px;
            font-family: "Arial Rounded MT Bold" ;

            padding-left: 50px ;
            padding-top: 20px;
            cursor: pointer;
            padding-right: 1px;
};

.meaning{
            display: none;
};

.mystyle{
           display: inline-block;
           padding-left: 100px;
           font-size: 30px;
           font-family: "Arial Black";
           font-weight: normal;
};
```

Comment: You'll have to show the HTML, and how you include the JS file in your page. Also, have you checked in your browser console for any errors? That might give you a clue.

Comment: Side note; with a little refactoring, this logic could be condensed considerably.

Comment: here is the html. sorry for the untidiness. im fairly new at javascript and still trying to get a handle on tings. i appreciate the help.

Comment: `application/javascript` is wrong. It is `text/javascript` If that doesn't fix it, can you open your site and ctrl+shift+i to open up the console and look for any errors?

Comment: switched application to text but still not working. also console is completely blank with no errors

Answer (score 1):

Make sure both files are in same repo. / path. Try pasting your code in these files.

**Make sure to remove `;` at the end of css classes from css files.**

here is a sample starter.

`index.html`

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>

 <head>
 <style>
  .mystyle {
    display: none;
  }
 </style>
 </head>

<body>
<div id="app"> </div>
<li id="refer">Hit Me!</li>
<ul>
    <li>
        <span id="refer_meaning" class="meaning">
            to tell a reader to look somewhere else in a book for more information about something.
        </span>
    </li>
</ul>
</body>
<script src="index.js"></script>
</html>
```

`index.js`

```
// Write Javascript code!
const appDiv = document.getElementById('app');
appDiv.innerHTML = `<h1>Click Me</h1>`;

appDiv.addEventListener('click', () => { appDiv.innerHTML = `<h1>JS starter</h1>` })

document.getElementById("refer").addEventListener("click", function () {
var element = document.getElementById("refer_meaning");
element.classList.toggle("mystyle");
});
```

Ping me incase of any query

Comment: post your full Html file so I will update my answer and find error. BTW I have added a sample js and html file to get started.
Just open html file in browser to see output and event listening.

Comment: i have added the full html above.

Comment: you can try my code. It seems ur styles are not linked properly Leme check

Comment: sorry but you have to share styles as well :/ for full tesing

Comment: you code is working fine seems like you have path issue make sure to keep all files in on repo and open html file in browser. Or tell me how you are running your code ?

Comment: posted styles sheet as well, and all the pages are in one directory

Comment: one more thing u dont need to add `;` at the end of css classes :/ remove first

Comment: Yes remove `;` from css and you are done that was the error . :)
If it works kindly accept ans

Comment: If you problem is resolved kindly accept the ans. so community can get help from it as well. Thanks